# Debian 9 LXDE Autologin doesn't work

Tags: debian, lxde, auto-login, debian-stretch

I've set in lightdm.conf these 2 settings (under the Seat:* section) and the autologin doesn't work. It still ask me for user and password

```
autologin-user=user
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

I've tried with this setting in addition, but it still doesn't work

```
user-session=default
```

In addition, the checkbox "Don't ask for password on login" is disabled and not checked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Find a solution which works for me. Adding this setting in lightdm.conf :

```
greeter-session=lightdm-xsession
```

The value name is from

```
ls /usr/share/xgreeters/*.desktop
```

Pick the one you use.

Answer (score 6):

The section is probably wrong/missing. Create `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/02_user.conf` with the following content:

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=<user>
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

Comment: This worked very well., and it is better to create a file named 01_debian.conf if there are none other there. Remember though, that setting autologin for guest will not work if autologin for user is set. local user donald trumps guest :-)

Answer (score 1):

My last answer worked only one time. I had to edit 
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf

```
[Seat:*]
greeter-session=lightdm-greeter
greeter-hide-users=false
autologin-session=true
#autologin-user=username
autologin-user-timeout=1
session-wrapper=/etc/X11/Xsession
```

(If `greeter-hide-users=true` I ever had to type my username. )

**And Also** in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

```
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
autologin-user= username
```